# Duplicate key Entry when no values are duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am getting a very weird duplicate entry error when no values are even identical...

```
INSERT INTO offer_status (id,user_id,sql_id,disabled) 
VALUES ('8854011812','8854','11812','0')
```

Returns:

> `#1062` - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'

This does not make sense to me at all!

Note: This code is not normally executed, I am just trying to debug. Normally in my PHP I have:

```
$offer=$campid;
$id=$user_id.'0'.$offer;
$sql="INSERT INTO offer_status (id,user_id,sql_id,disabled) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE disabled=VALUES(disabled)";

    $db->prepare($sql)->execute(array($id, $user_id, $offer, 0));
```

`id` is the primary key. What is going on here?

Added: Result of `DESC offer_status`:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(12) NO  PRI NULL    
user_id int(12) NO      NULL    
sql_id  int(12) NO  MUL NULL    
favor   tinyint(4)  NO      0   
disabled    tinyint(4)  NO      0   
pref    int(2)  NO      0
```

Comment: can you post the result of this query along with your question `DESC offer_status` ?

Comment: Which query do you want the result of?

Comment: this one `DESC offer_status`

Comment: Done...hopefully you can read...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`8854011812` is out of `int` range. It will be replaced by the max `int` number which is `2147483647`.

The second time you insert a value greather than the `int` max, you will get a duplicate key error.

If you need such high numbers you can change your data type to `bigint`.

Comment: I changed the the `id` type to int(35) in the data structure but the same thing is still happening...did I miss a step?

Comment: Chnage to `bigint`. `int` just does not have such a big range, no matter what you write in that `()`.

Comment: Would that be better for query optimization, or a varchar?

Comment: If it is a number then always go for a numeric data type rathe than a string.

Answer (score 1):

Oh i see. Since you have mentioned that `ID` is the primary, I guess the data type of which is  `int` and which the maximum value for `SIGNED INT` is `2147483647`. You should have change the data type to `decimal(15,0)` or `VARCHAR(15)` so the value will be cattered.

The value you are inserting `8854011812` is kinda out of range to which an `int` can hold.

Comment: you can't have that value. better use `DECIMAL(12,0)` or numeric.

Comment: There is no need for a fixed-point data type like `decimal` when using natural numbers.